# Get the correct background color

Tags: css, background-color

I have to create and design a drop-down list like this [image]

My code:

```html
<select name="member_area" id="member-box" style="
    background-color: #FCFCFC !important;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    font-weight: 300;
    background: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/trico-arrows-1/24/ExpandUpDownSmall-512.png') no-repeat right #ddd;
    background-position: 98%;
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 8px;
    background-size: 14px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px  solid #cccccc;
    box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px -10px 36px -28px inset;
    text-shadow: 1.1px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
">
      <option value="Members">Members</option>
      <option value="Member_1">Member 1</option>
      <option value="Member_2">Member 2</option>
      <option value="Member_3">Member 3</option>
   </select>
```

It results as this [image]

I am not getting the correct background color.
What should I do to get the correct background color?

Comment: You are getting the correct background color.

Comment: @Ismailp Sorry for the late reply. Yes, upon introspection. I have to work on box-shadow and text-shadow. The background-color is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your Hexa code **#FCFCFC** is giving **white color** and therefore, your select tag has **white background**.

What else color you want to choose? Write its hexa code and it is working perfectly fine...

Comment: @Harpreet Singh Kapula does that work?

Comment: @Eatsum ul haq  Sorry for the late reply. Upon more close introspection. The background-color is fine. I have to work on the box-shadow and text-shadow. Thank you for the advice.